# Does anyone know how to work out the amount of sodium sulfate present in water?

Tags: analytical-chemistry

I need to find out 2 ways to determine the amount of sodium sulfate in an aqueous solution. I have searched the internet for assays.

Answer (score 1):

I would use barium nitrate and weigh the precipitate, assuming that the solution does not contain any other sulfates.  Barium sulfate solubility is only 0.0002448 g/100 mL at room temperature.  An experiment is here http://web.iitd.ac.in/~arunku/files/CEL212_Y14/CEL%20212%20Lab%204%20Sulfate.pdf. You could also try something like this http://www.thomassci.com/Laboratory-Supplies/Water-Quality-Test-Kits/_/SULFATE-TEST-KIT.